# Selecting a specific item in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 6 items in my listbox.

I want to it so that if I click the first 2 in the listbox I can set a random number. I don't need to know how make a random number.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex = 1)
{
    int no1 = random.Next(10, 50);
}
```

Just after 'if' I see the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Answer (score 6):

Should be: `if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)`

The `=` operator is assignment, `==` is equality.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use two equal signs to check for equality.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
  int no1 = random.Next(10, 50);
}
```

[You can read more about C# equality on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes in case of int you can't use = operator to check equality you just need to check using == operator, ok in the case of bool compiler can't give any error but it can resign.mean to say.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
 {
   int no1 = random.Next(10, 50);
 }
```

it's correct one in case of Bool

suppose you have to write.

```
bool test=false;
if(test=true)
{
 //some code goes here 
 }
```

it won't give you compiler error it will reassign test.